# Icons needed for iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Could you please point me to a complete list of ALL the different icons (dimensions + name) needed for an iOS (iPhone/iPad) application? (retina or non-retina display)

> e.g.
>
> AAAAAxAAAA@2x.png, etc

I've been looking for a solid reference for that (even on SO), and I'm still not sure...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: @janusfidel Thanks janus. I've had a look into this document before. However, I can't see any naming guidelines it; am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the names and sizes of iOS icons:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

And here are the names and sizes of other images, such as iPad 3 retina launch image:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

App Icons in the Programming Guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1

Note that this is correct and complete at the time of writing. But these may change in future! So when this post gets old, check Human Interface Guidelines on developer.apple.com instead.

Answer (score 6):

Following table shows the icon size.
[image]

[image]

Comment: None of these are retina though, check my Programming Guide link.

Answer (score 2):

These are what you are looking for:

[**Mobiledev**](http://www.mobiledev.nl/ios-artwork-what-icons-and-images-are-needed-for-an-ios-app)
[**Tumblr**](http://mrgan.tumblr.com/post/708404794/ios-app-icon-sizes)
[**Icon handbook**](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/ios/)

I am sure you'll have a complete answer to your query by following these.